# The split string by regex does not work fine in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

in javascript i am using split method by regular expression for below string, but it does not work fine in javascript code, also i tested it on some online regex tester website like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/38prd) and it works fine!

the string: `"$1 $2 $3 $5 $7 hello"`.

the result : `["","$7 ","hello"]`

Expected result : `["hello"]`

here is my codes: [online example!](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXTO6AG6A8MY)

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "$1 $2 $3 $5 $7 hello";
    var res = str.split(/([$][0-9]+[ ]*)+/gu);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display the array value after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The capturing group makes the regex engine put back the captured value into the resulting array. Besides, the empty element that results in a match between start of string and the match next to it is added, too.

You can use a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) and remove empty items afterwards:

```js
var str = "$1 $2 $3 $5 $7 hello";
console.log(str.split(/\s*(?:\$\d+\s*)+/).filter(Boolean));
```

**Pattern details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:\$\d+\s*)+` - 1 or more occurrences of

  - `\$` - a `$` sign
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6WnJuh/1)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "$1 $2 $3 $5 $7 hello $5";
    var subst = ``;
    var res= str.replace(/([$][0-9]?.)/gu, subst);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display the array value after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: It would also fully capture `Hello $1 test $2 $3`. I guess not what OP wants